# How to coerce stslist.freq to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, traminer

I am doing some describtive sequence analysis using the "TraMineR" library. I want to report my findings via R-Markdown in html format. For formating tables I use "kable" and "kableExtra".
To get the frequency and propotions of the most common sequences I use `seqtab()`. The result is an `stslist.freq` object. When I try to coerce it to a dataframe, the dataframe is not containing any frequencies and proportions.

I tried to print the results of `seqtab()` and store this result again. This gives me the dataframe I desire. However there are two "problems" with that: (1) I don't understand what is happening here and it seems like a "dirty" trick, (2) as a result I also get the output of the print command in my final  html document if I don't split the code in multiple chunks and disable the ouput in the specific chunk.

Here is some code to replicate the problem:

```r
library("TraMineR")

#Data creation
data.long  <- data.frame(
  id=rep(1:50, each=4),
  time = c(0,1,2,3),
  status = sample(letters[1:2], 200, replace = TRUE),
  weight=rep(runif(50, 0, 1), each=4)
)

#reshape
data.wide <- reshape(data.long, v.names = "status", idvar="id", direction="wide", timevar="time")

#sequence
sequence <- seqdef(data.wide,
                   var=c("status.0", "status.1", "status.2", "status.3"), 
                   weights=data.wide$weight)

#frequencies of sequences
##doesn't work:
seqtab.df1 <- as.data.frame(seqtab(sequence)) 

##works:
seqtab.df2 <- print(seqtab(sequence))
```

I expect the dataframe to be the same as the one saved in `seqtab.df2`, however either without using the print command or with "silently" (no output printed) using the print command.

Thank you very much for your help and let me know if I forgot something to make answering the question possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `class()` of the object returned by `seqtab`, it has the type

```
class(seqtab(sequence))
# [1] "stslist.freq" "stslist"      "data.frame"
```

so if we look at exactly, what's happening in the print statement for such an object we can get a clue what's going on

```
TraMineR:::print.stslist.freq
# function (x, digits = 2, width = 1, ...) 
# {
#     table <- attr(x, "freq")
#     print(table, digits = digits, width = width, ...)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x0000000003e831f8>
# <environment: namespace:TraMineR>
```

We see that what it's really giving you is the "freq" attribute. You can extract this directly and skip the `print()`

```
attr(seqtab(sequence), "freq")
#                     Freq   Percent
# a/3-b/1         4.283261 20.130845
# b/1-a/1-b/2     2.773341 13.034390
# a/2-b/1-a/1     2.141982 10.067073
# a/1-b/1-a/1-b/1 1.880359  8.837476
# a/1-b/2-a/1     1.723489  8.100203
# b/1-a/2-b/1     1.418302  6.665861
# b/2-a/1-b/1     1.365099  6.415813
# a/1-b/3         1.241644  5.835586
# a/1-b/1-a/2     1.164434  5.472710
# a/2-b/2         1.092656  5.135360
```